# Macro to compare two worksheets and highlight where a change has occured

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a macro within a workbook that can be used as a comparison tool.

Historical data will be added to Worksheet 1 'Historical'.  Then current data will be added to Worksheet 2 'New'.  The data is in exactly the same format.

The macro should look down column G in worksheet 1 (which is a key identifier) and also column O (which shows a status).  Then this data should be compared to column G and O in worksheet 2.

If column G is a match but column O has changed then the entire row, from Worksheet 2 'New', should be pasted into Worksheet 3 'Results'.

Example;

Worksheet 1 'Historical' - Column G, 123456789 and Column O, Not Valid

Worksheet 2 'New' - Column G, 123456789 and Column O, Valid

As there is a match in column G but the status has changed, the row from Worksheet 2 will be pasted into the next free row in Worksheet 3 'Results'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have played around with adding Vlookup and Countif into the macro without much success.

Comment: Will the Id's in column G ever be duplicated, or are they always unique values?

Comment: Hi Dave, on some occasions the ID's in G will be duplicated if we have more than one record on that specific account.  This is rare but can happen.  Thanks

Comment: I'm using this formula in a separate sheet; =IF(New!O2=VLOOKUP(New!G2,Historical!$G$2:$O$1000,9,0),"","CHANGED")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may give you an idea, hope it's helpful.

```
Sub matchMe()
    Dim wS As Worksheet, wT As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim cel1 As Range, cel2 As Range

    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With wS
        Set r1 = .Range("G1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("G:G").Column).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With wT
        Set r2 = .Range("G1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("G:G").Column).End(xlUp))
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cel1 In r1
        With Application
            Set cel2 = .Index(r2, .Match(cel1.Value, r2, 0)) 'find match in sheet2
            If Err = 0 Then
                If cel1.Offset(, 8) <> cel2.Offset(, 8) Then copyRow cel2 'if difference, copy
            End If
            Err.Clear
        End With
    Next cel1
End Sub

Sub copyRow(cel As Range)
    Dim w As Worksheet, r As Range
    Set w = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set r = w.Cells(w.Rows.Count, Columns("G:G").Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'next row
    cel.EntireRow.Copy w.Cells(r.Row, 1)
End Sub
```